# Importing SVN into git with SubGit - git repo has no branches?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, subgit

I installed Subgit because our team wants to switch an existing SVN repo  to git. 
The structure is, as far as I can tell, pretty standard:

`http://svn.local/project1/trunk` < `trunk`

`http://svn.local/project1/branches` < `branches`

`http://svn.local/project1/tags` < `tags`

My problem is that the imported git repo contains no branches.
Here is how I did the import:

CD-d to ~/git and ran `subgit configure --svn-url http://svn.local/project1/trunk project1`. 
The result of this command was:

```
    CONFIGURATION SUCCESSFUL

    To complete SubGit installation do the following:

    1) Adjust Subversion to Git branches mapping if necessary:
/home/az/git/project1/subgit/config <br>

    2) Define at least one Subversion credentials in default SubGit passwd file at:
    /home/az/git/project1/subgit/passwd
   OR configure SSH or SSL credentials in the [auth] section of:
    /home/az/git/project1/subgit/config <br>

    3) Optionally, add custom authors mapping to the authors.txt file(s) at:
/home/az/git/project1/subgit/authors.txt

    4) Run SubGit 'install' command:
    subgit install project1
```

I did step 2 - added valid credentials for the SVN server. It's LDAP-enabled, if that matters, but the credentials are verified and definitely valid. I then ran `subgit install project1`

Output:

```
SubGit version 2.0.3 ('Patrick') build #2796

Translating Subversion revisions to Git commits...

Subversion revisions translated: 890.
Total time: 12 seconds.

INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

So I can see that it pulled some history from the SVN repo. However, executing `git branch -a` inside the `project1` folder returns nothing. `git fetch` says I have to specify a remote repository, but I'm not sure what I have to put there. How can I fix this, so I can finally let others clone from the `project1` repo and see the code and history?

Comment: From the look of doc, correct way would have been `subgit configure --svn-url http://svn.local/project1 project1.git`

Comment: I ended up using `git svn` and it worked, followed [this procedure](http://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git/) in case anyone is interested